# When I post value data by c# to php, occur 500 error

Tags: c#, php, server

I post formdata from my c# program to php in my server by this code:

```
byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
webClient.Dispose();
```

but response from server is

> Internal Server Error 500.

In addition it was done in localhost (xampp) correctly but in my server give me **Internal Server Error 500.**

When I use above code two times, my server not give me 500 error and values uploaded correctly:

```
byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
webClient.Dispose();

byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
webClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: It does mean what it says - internal **server** error. Nothing wrong with your C# code - the problem is in your PHP server code. Just debug it.

Comment: @AvsenevSlava no it is http

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967468/httpwebrequest-post-gives-500-server-error , because of the same behaivour with the second request